# Improve performace of string search using Patter.compile in large files

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have huge text files whose size can range from 500KB to 500MB. I have a list of keywords that needs to be found in the file content. The no. of keywords can be up to 400,000.
Right now I'm using the below code to find the keywords in the file content

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\harshita.sethi\\Desktop\\merge\\MNT.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }

    String content = fileContent.toString();
    Set<List<String>> keywords = getDbQuery(); // size can be up to 4*10^5

    for (List<String> key : keywords) {
        if (checkOccurence(content, key.get(0))) {
            //Do Somethng
        }
    }
}

private static boolean checkOccurence(String content, String keyword) {
    Boolean flag = false;
    try {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + keyword + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
            flag = m.find();


    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        System.out.println("cannot report occrence of " + keyword);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The problem is with huge file size it takes a lot of time to scan through the file. I have done all sorts of testing and came to the conclusion that Pattern.Compile is making the code progress slow.
I have read on the internet since Pattern.compile compiles the regex everytime the function is called it consumes a lot of time.

Can anyone please suggest how can improve the performance of this code so that the string search is faster.

PS: I'm restricted to use Java 6 version.

**Edit -**

I tried the compiling all the keywords before the for loop as suggested by few people. I can see there is no much difference in the code execution time.

Although I noticed that by removing the `boundary regex`, the performance of the code changed drastically. It just took few seconds to complete the full run where it was taking 8-10 mins earlier. But by removing `boundary regex`, I'm not getting the desired output.

**Question -** Is there a way to fine tune the performance using boundaries. Why did the performance changed drastically?

My aim(for example) is to get

- `false` if `abcd` is found while searching `abc` and
- `true` if `abc.` or `abc,` or `abc` etc is found while searching for `abc`.

Comment: You can store compiled patterns and reuse them.

Comment: The keyword will change in each iteration. How can I compile the pattern in advance then?

Comment: Better yet, you can combine the keywords and build only one pattern.

Comment: And I don't think people understand what lakh is. Yeah it's pretty simple to google it but...

Comment: if the total number of unique keywords is reasonable, you can store the patterns in a hashmap, and instead of compiling a new pattern, first check if it's present in the map. Obviously, it adds some overhead, but still might be faster.

Comment: @Andrey ok. I'll give it a try and get back

Comment: Also you don't need `Boolean`, use `boolean`.

Comment: @Andrey  I changed the code based on your suggestion. See my update.

Comment: Do you have Unicode characters outside ASCII?

Comment: @Andrey These are custom files generated by some program. They may have Unicode characters outside ASCII

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to load key words and compile all patters before the search process.

The next step to improve the performance is to use the Java 8 stream api which allows you to paralyze the compile and search process.

I think that can help.

Comment: I'm restricted to use Java 6. Still I'll try compiling patterns before and get back.

Comment: I changed the code as u suggested. See the question update.